# How to understand which variables are correlated with each other in a correlation scatter plot

Tags: r, correlation

I have obtained a pair graph from mtcars dataset.[image: Pair Graph]

How to know from this pair graph which variables are more correlated with each other?

Answer (score 9):

One other option would be to use a correlation matrix and then plot it using the `corrplot` package:

```
require(corrplot)
corrplot.mixed(cor(mtcars),tl.col='black')
```

[image]

You can see the correlation coefficients and thus find correlated variables.

You can also use the `PerformanceAnalytics` package :

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
chart.Correlation(mtcars,hist=T)
```

You can see the histograms of the values, the lines as in the `pairs` function, the correlation coefficients and the significance levels.

[image]

Comment: So which variables are correlated with each other according to this plot?

Comment: cyl and disp have a 0.9 correlation coefficient so they are well positively-correlated. mpg and wt have a coefficient of -0.87 so they are negatively-correlated. The closer to 1 or -1 the higher the correlation

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know correlation coefficient directly, user `pairs.panels` function from [`psych`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf) package.

```
library(psych)
pairs.panels(mtcars[,1:6])
```

This plot provides more insights about data than `pairs` function.
[image: Output]

Comment: So which variables are most correlated according to this plot?

Comment: @PankajSharma Variables are marked along the diagonal, scatter plots in lower triangle and correlation coefficients in upper triangle. So, using matrix notation, for variables `A[i,i]` and `A[j,j]`, corresponding scatter plot is `A[j, i]` and correlation coefficient is `A[i,j]`. Given this much information can you figure out which two variables are most correlated ?

Answer (score 0):

whichever adhere to a  fitted  *straight* red line well, ie. change in synch with each other. Like *mpg ~ wt*  one ( 5th on 1st row) .

Sometimes, if the points lie close to the line but the line is curved (like *disp ~ wt*) , it's good nonlinear  association and one can still be defined by other, but if you compute  a correlation coefficient  it will be small.

Comment: Please show which variables are correlated in this graph and how?

Comment: It's not necessary that they fit a straight line. In fact `disp ~ wt` has higher correlation coefficient than `mpg ~ wt`.

> cor(mtcars$disp, mtcars$wt)
[1] 0.8879799
> cor(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$wt)
[1] -0.8676594

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
d_cor <- as.matrix(cor(mtcars[,1:6]))
d_cor_melt <- arrange(melt(d_cor), -abs(value))
thresold = 0.7
filter(d_cor_melt, abs(value) > thresold  & value !=1)
```

[image]